# MVC2 c# multiple forms in table. One form overwriting other form elements on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have an ASP.Net MVC2 application that has a table with text boxes where users can enter commentary and click update to update a single row of data. Each row of the table is generated with a for each loop via a call to the db based on a date, entered by the user and is wrapped in a form with the name `commentaryForm` - like this

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)
       using (Html.BeginForm("Commentary", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "commentaryForm", id = "commentaryForm" }))
       { %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= Html.TextBox("comDate", item.aReportingDate.ToString().Substring(0, 10), new { @readonly = true, @class = "readOnlyTBox" })%></td>
<td><%= Html.Encode(item.BPM)%></td>
<td><%= Html.Encode(item.criticality)%></td>
<td><%= Html.Encode(item.team)%></td>
<td><%= Html.Encode(Convert.ToInt32(item.newIn))%></td>
<td><%= Html.Encode(Convert.ToInt32(item.outsideSLA))%></td>
<td><%= Html.TextArea("why", item.commentaryWhy, new { @class = "commentaryInput" })%></td>
<td><%= Html.TextArea("what", item.commentaryWhat, new { @class = "commentaryInput" })%></td>
<td><%= Html.TextBox("when", item.commentaryWhen, new { @class = "when" })%></td>
<td id="resultsTd"><input type="submit" class="submitButton noMargin" value="Update" /></td>
<td class=""><%= Html.Encode(item.commentaryId)%> <%= Html.TextBox("id", item.commentaryId, new { @class = "when", type = "", value = item.commentaryId })%></td>

</tr>

<% }%>
```

clicking update in a row calls this controller, where the arrays contain the values from the collection of individual textboxes / text areas in that row.

```
public ActionResult Commentary(string[] why, string[] what, DateTime[] when, int[] id)
    {

        var reportingDate = new DateTime();
        reportingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["comDate"]);
        if (reportingDate.ToString().Substring(0, 10).Equals(@"01/01/0001"))
        {
            DateTime latestDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            reportingDate = latestDay;
            ViewData["start"] = latestDay.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
        }
        else
            ViewData["start"] = reportingDate.ToString().Substring(0, 10);


        var model = new List<commentaryVModel>();

        if (why != null && what != null && when != null && id != null)
            {
            DataLayer.Updatedata(id, why, what, when);
            }
        model = DataLayer.viewCommentary(model, reportingDate);
        return View(model);

    }
```

`DataLayer.Updatedata` and `DataLayer.viewCommentary(model, reportingDate)` seem to work fine on step through, and values are as expected.

The problem is that when the page reloads after you click update, the values in all the table rows have been replaced by the values from the row you updated! Only in the DOM that the user sees, not on the database though! Weird!

Can anyone help? Thanks! I've posted the code for the database methods below, I can't post a screen shot yet as this is my first question.

```
public static List<commentaryVModel> viewCommentary(List<commentaryVModel> model, DateTime reportingDate)
{
        SqlConnection con = DataLayer.getConnection();
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        string commandString = DataLayer.Commentary();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // add parameters
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportingDate", reportingDate);

        try
        {
                // execute a reader with the command
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                {
                    // loop in the result and fill the list
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // add items in the list
                        model.Add(new commentaryVModel()
                        {
                            BPM = reader["BPM"] as string,
                            aReportingDate = (DateTime)reader["date"],
                            team = reader["Team"] as string,
                            criticality = reader["Criticality"] as string,
                            newIn = (decimal)reader["NewIn"],
                            outsideSLA = (decimal)reader[@"OutsideSLA"],
                            commentaryId = (int)reader[@"Id"],
                            commentaryWhy = reader[@"CommentaryWhy"] as string,
                            commentaryWhat = reader[@"CommentaryWhat"] as string,
                            commentaryWhen = reader[@"CommentaryWhen"] as string
                        });
                    }
                }
        }
        catch
        { }
        finally
        {
                // 3. close the reader
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }

                // close the connection
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
        }

public static void Updatedata(int[] id, string[] why, string[] what, DateTime[] when)
{
        SqlConnection con = DataLayer.getConnection();
        try
        {
            string fullString = null;
            // prepare command string
            for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)

            {
                string updateString = @"
            UPDATE   tCommentary
            SET      CommentaryWhy = '" + why[i] + "'" +
                    ",CommentaryWhat = '" + what[i] + "'" +
                    ",CommentaryWhen = '" + when[i] + "'" +
            "WHERE    rowId = " +  id[i] + " ";
            fullString = fullString + " " + updateString;
            }

            // 1. Instantiate a new command with a query and connection
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(fullString, con);
            // 2. Call ExecuteNonQuery to send command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch
        { }
        finally
        {
            // Close the connection
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Look at your HTML. Most likely you have duplicated IDs in your forms which is not allowed.

Comment: At first glance, all your forms get the same ID (as bobek mentioned) and the same name. I would change that.
Have you experienced behavior in different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

When model binding to a list you need to append a unique identifier to each row, in order to keep the generated id's unique.

Here is an example using a for loop rather than a foreach (its written in old school asp views, not razor)

```
<%@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<IList<Book>>" %>

    <% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>

      <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Title) %>
      <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Author) %>
      <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].DatePublished) %> 

    <% } %>
```

This will generate textboxes with unique id's allowing you to post back multiple items in a single form. You're obviously trying to make multiple forms, which could still work, just give each form a unique id.

Take a look at phil haacks classic article on the subject. i know its targeted to earlier versions of mvc, but the principle is still the same.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx